# appcelerator titanium iPhone twitter timeline resize

Tags: iphone, twitter, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm working in appcelerator and I have a tab which is the profile. On the top half there is the profile picture, the name, and other misc items, then on the bottom half is a twitter timeline. When i started putting on the twitter timeline code, it takes up the whole screen. Is there a way to reduce the timeline to only take up a portion of the screen to be able to see the other items?

This is my twitter timeline code:

```
var twitterUserName = "foundationsix";
var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
httpClient.timeout = 10000;
httpClient.open("GET","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/" + 
"user_timeline.json?count=10&screen_name=" + twitterUserName);

var twitterData = [];
httpClient.onload = function() {
try {


    var tweets = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

        var tweetText = tweets[i].text;
        var user = tweets[i].user.screen_name;
        var avatar = tweets[i].user.profile_image_url;
        var created_at = tweets[i].created_at;

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({hasChild:true,
            height:'auto'});

            var postView = Ti.UI.createView({
            height:'55',
            top:5,
            bottom:5,
            left:5,
            right:5,

        });

        var avatarImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:avatar,
            left:0,
            top:0,
            height:48,
            width:48
        });

        postView.add(avatarImageView);

        var userLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:user,
            left:54,
            width:120,
            top:-48,
            bottom:2,
            height:16,
            textAlign:'left',
            color:'#444444',
            font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:14,
                fontWeight:'bold'}
        });

        postView.add(userLabel);

        var dateLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:created_at,
            right:0,
            top:-18,
            bottom:2,
            height:14,
            textAlign:'right',
            width:110,
            color:'#444444',
            font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:12}
        });

        postView.add(dateLabel);

        var tweetTextLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:tweetText,
            left:54,
            top:0,
            bottom:2,
            height:'auto',
            width:236,
            textAlign:'left',
            font:{fontSize:14}
        });

        postView.add(tweetTextLabel);
        row.add(postView);
        twitterData[i] = row;
    }


    var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({data:twitterData,
        minRowHeight:58});
    win1.add(tableview);

} 
catch(E) {
    alert(E);
}
 };
          httpClient.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind .. We need to use either top and left or bottom and right.. dont mix up top and bottom in same element....

coming to solution to yours .. give top to table so that it goes down .......

i have created top view where you can specify username and etc

below you can post timeline

```
var win1=Ti.UI.createWindow()


///// this is top portion 
var topView=Ti.UI.createView({
    top:0,
    left:0,
    height:100,
    background:"#2d2d2d"
})

var username=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"foundationsix",
    color:"#fff"
})

topView.add(username)
 win1.add(topView)





var twitterUserName = "foundationsix";
var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
httpClient.timeout = 10000;
httpClient.open("GET","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/" + "user_timeline.json?count=10&screen_name=" + twitterUserName);

var twitterData = [];
httpClient.onload = function() {
try {


    var tweets = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var i=0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

        var tweetText = tweets[i].text;
        var user = tweets[i].user.screen_name;
        var avatar = tweets[i].user.profile_image_url;
        var created_at = tweets[i].created_at;

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({hasChild:true,
            height:'auto'});

            var postView = Ti.UI.createView({height:55});

        var avatarImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:avatar,
            left:0,
            top:0,
            height:48,
            width:48
        });

        postView.add(avatarImageView);

        var userLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:user,
            left:54,
            width:120,
            top:-48,
            bottom:2,
            height:16,
            textAlign:'left',
            color:'#444444',
            font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:14,
                fontWeight:'bold'}
        });

        postView.add(userLabel);

        var dateLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:created_at,
            right:0,
            top:-18,
            bottom:2,
            height:14,
            textAlign:'right',
            width:110,
            color:'#444444',
            font:{fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS',fontSize:12}
        });

        postView.add(dateLabel);

        var tweetTextLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:tweetText,
            left:54,
            top:0,
            bottom:2,
            height:'auto',
            width:236,
            textAlign:'left',
            font:{fontSize:14}
        });

        postView.add(tweetTextLabel);
        row.add(postView);
        twitterData[i] = row;
    }


    var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        data:twitterData,
        minRowHeight:58,
        top:100
        });
    win1.add(tableview);

} 
catch(E) {
    alert(E);
}
 };
          httpClient.send();


win1.open()
```